# Cosets & Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ have order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes. Either $G$ is cyclic, or every element $x \ne e$ in $G$ has order $p$ or $q$.

---

So probably cases, right? I know I need to use Lagrange's Theorem, but I'm not sure how. So $G$ has $pq$ elements... Im just confused

Answer (score 2):

Lagrange's theorem says every element has order dividing the order of the group. If there's an element with order equal to the order of the group, $G$ is cyclic. If there isn't, then every element has order strictly less than $pq$ and dividing it. There aren't that many divisors of $pq$ -- only $1,p,q$. That should do it.

Edit: Given your version of Lagrange's theorem -- for every subgroup $H\subset G$ of a finite group, we have $|H|\mid|G|$ -- take $H=\langle x \rangle$ for any element $x\in G$. Then $|H|=|x|$.

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem states that the order of a group is a multiple of a subgroup of that group.